# Powerpoint equations shortcut

Tags: microsoft-office

I am working with Office 2007, and I notice that in Word exists this shortcut:

[image]

I am looking to the Equation shortcut that appears next to the Symbol one. I would like to know if there is a way to have the same shortcut in Powerpoint 2007.

Thanks

Comment: that's a "button", not a shortcut. Shortcut refers to a keyboard shortcut like Ctrl+C

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint 2007, the Equation is available in Equation Editor, which was a separate window but not in the ribbon.

> To access the Equation Editor in PowerPoint 2007 and earlier, choose Insert, Object. In the Insert Object dialog box, scroll down and select Microsoft Equation 3.0. You’ll see a window that looks like this.

View more in [here](https://www.ellenfinkelstein.com/pptblog/how-to-display-equations-and-formulas-in-powerpoint/).

[image: Equation Editor]

You can also refer to [Using Equation Editor with PowerPoint 2007](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00832_Using_Equation_Editor_with_PowerPoint_2007.htm)

Comment: if you copied text from others you must put them in block quotes. Besides equation editor is completely different from the "equation" button in Word 2007+ and PowerPoint/Excel 2010+